# How to lazy load CSV and Topojson data in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, lazy-loading, topojson

I am developing different graphs using D3 Library and to build charts and different maps it uses CSV and GeoJson respectively.

Everything is rendering properly but the only issue is that it takes huge time when page is get loaded and also it does not allow to scroll and feels like the page stucks there.

So I was wondering whether there is any plugin which will help to load data slowly or load it lazily?

Comment: Do you have some code of how you are doing it currently? Are you calling a d3.csv function on page load or something similar?

Comment: post a link to check -- it could be because of your internet speed

Comment: Yes @Ankit I am using d3.csv

Comment: its not internet speed issue. I am trying to load data around 5 to 6 mb on page load. is there any way to load it slowly and end user do not feel any lag on page

Comment: I don't think there is anything in Javascript to do that. You will have to implement it yourself as it depends on your requirements. One way for example is to create another file on server with aggregated values which you show on page load while asynchronously load all the data.